# How can I create a dialog using TimePicker's header without manually copying every style and dimension?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I need to create a dialog just like the image below. It has the header like the TimePicker dialog, but with a GridLayout in the content area.

I tried copying the source code from Android repository, but as it uses several styles/textappearances/attrs, which is making this a little harder.

So, is there any possible way to create my custom dialog, using TimePicker's header and styles from material design (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml) without having to copy them to my project?

[image: sample]